# Laravel Session expiration event

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

Is it possible to fire some event when user session is expired ?

As example (session expiration time 30 mins):

1. User logged into website;
2. Made several actions;
3. Session expired;
4. No More actions with website.

So User has to be log out from external discourse forum.

Any good ideas how to achieve this ?

Comment: Token with `expired_at` field.

Comment: Could you pease elaborate on your suggestion ? Just not sure how can I use it to trigger additional logout.

Comment: When the session expire - user automatically out of authorized area. You don't need an event.

Comment: thanks for suggestion. As I noted in question there is an additional need to log out this user from external forum. I don't need a case when main user session is expired but this user is still has possibility to make some actions on forum

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you set the expiration time on the forum the same as the main site?

Comment: There is no way to simply set it the same. However I considered this approach

Comment: There is no way to simply set it the same (https://meta.discourse.org/t/decrease-default-session-timeout/62621) . However It will be good to have some hook on log out because if you set period the same you still might have some un-synchronization cases